# Stacking Images CSS

Tags: css, image, fluid

I know its easy to stack images on top of one another but I just wondered if this could be achieved but maintaining a fluid image? As soon as I use the position attribute, I have to supply a width. Then the image won't re-size with the browser.

Thanks for any help.

Joe

Comment: Can you show some code that you have now? `position` properties (and I presume you mean property, not attribute) don't require a width.

Comment: This question is pointless without code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course use `width: 100%;`. Also, you wouldn't need to put them inside divs if you just specify `display: block;` on the img element. You may have to specify `max-width`, but that depends on your particular application and required browser support.

Comment: I feel a tit! Theres me using all these fancy advanced techniques and I always though you had to fix a width for positioning!

Comment: It happens to the best of us :) If my answer helped, could you please mark it as correct?

Comment: @jhodgson4 ..."feel a tit"?  I assume that's another British expression that just *sounds* dirty?  (Google didn't help!)

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes, your assumption is correct. It has no relation with breasts in this context.

Comment: @ashleedawg no tits were harmed in the making of this comment. Just egos. Apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A `width : 100%` works with `position : absolute` if `display : block`

Your problem is likely that you have only absolutely positionned img in your div, so its dimensions are null (because positioning rules.)

Two way to solve this :

- make one img not absolutely positionned. Its dimensions will be be dimensions of the parent div
- use a transparent img, with `position : relative`,  with the same dimension than your real imgs : it's quite dirty, but it'll set the parent div dimensions.

These'll work only if your imgs' dimensions are the same. Otherwise, you must use a JS solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this solution works great but the other guy got there first.

Answer (score 1):

Make the photos the background on either an empty `<img>` or `<div>` with something like this

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container > div {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

<div class="container">

   <div style="background: url('myimage1.jpg');"><!-- nothing --></div>
   <div style="background: url('myimage2.jpg');"><!-- nothing --></div>
   <div style="background: url('myimage3.jpg');"><!-- nothing --></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Would this scale the background image without using background-size?

Comment: No, it wouldn't scale the image by default.  You would have it at full resolution and as the container expanded, so would the size of its contained `div`s showing more of the photo